# Weighted matrix max-norm equivalent representations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Given the definition of weighted matrix max-norm as

\begin{gather*}
\left \| A \right \| _\infty ^w = \max \limits _{x \ne 0} \frac{\left \| A x\right \| _\infty ^w}{\left \| x\right \| _\infty ^w}  \tag{1} \label{eq:special}
\end{gather*}

and the definition of weighted vector max-norm as
\begin{gather*}
\left \| x\right \| _\infty ^w = \max \limits _{i} |\frac{x_i}{w_i}|, w_i>0.  \tag{2} \label{eq:special1}
\end{gather*}

I'm trying to prove there's an equivalent representation

\begin{gather*}\left \| A \right \| _\infty ^w = \left \| |A|w \right \| _\infty ^w  \tag{3} \label{eq:special2}
\end{gather*}

but with no luck. I managed to prove $\left \| A \right \| _\infty := \max \limits _{x \ne 0} \frac{\left \| A x\right \| _\infty }{\left \| x\right \| _\infty } = \max \limits _i \sum \limits _j |a_{ij}|$, which seems related but didn't really help. Can you show me how to work it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what “equivalent representation” you are looking for. Are you trying to express $\Vert A \Vert_\infty^w$ in terms of  the “usual” matrix max-norm $\Vert A \Vert_\infty$?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I was trying to say that the definition in (1) can be manipulated into (3), i.e. the maximum over $x \ne 0$ in (1) should be equal to $\left \| Aw \right \| _\infty ^w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ denote the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(w)$. Note that $\|x\|_\infty^w = \|W^{-1}x\|$. It follows that 
$$
\begin{align}
\|A\|_\infty^w &= \max_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_\infty^w}{\|x\|_\infty^w} 
= \max_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|W^{-1}Ax\|_\infty}{\|W^{-1}x\|_\infty}
= \max_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|W^{-1}A(Wy)\|_\infty}{\|W^{-1}(Wy)\|_\infty}
\\ & = \max_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|(W^{-1}AW)y\|_\infty}{\|y\|_\infty} = \|W^{-1}AW\|_\infty.
\end{align}
$$
Combining this with your characterization of $\|A\|_\infty$, we have 
$$
\|A\|_\infty^w = \max_i \sum_j \frac{w_j}{w_i}|a_{ij}| = \max_i \frac 1{w_i} (e_i^T|A|)w = \big\||A|w \big\|_\infty^w.
$$
In the above, $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector )i.e. the $i$th column of the identity matrix) and $|A|$ denotes the matrix whose entries are $|a_{ij}|$.